# How to modify a for cycle to Parallel.For? C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I created a really simple app to calculate *prime numbers* and then write them. I want to let it run on all cores, if a user chooses to calculate for example to `1 000 000`...

How can I convert my already functioning for cycle to run on all cores? 
I found out that there is a `Parallel.For` but I don't really know how to convert to that from my existing for cycle...

```
    {
        bool isPrime = true;
        int fPrime = Convert.ToInt32(txt_input.Text);
        Application.DoEvents();

        for (int i = 2; i <= fPrime; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= fPrime; j++)
            {

                if (i != j && i % j == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (isPrime)
            {
                txt_result.Text = txt_result.Text + "..." + i;
            }
            isPrime = true;
        }

        txt_result.Text = txt_result.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Done";
    }
```

Comment: Is `txt_result` a UI component? You can't use UI components (be it WinForms or WPF) from other threads. You should store intermediate results in locals, not fields or statics.

Comment: You can implement a by far more *efficient* prime tester (`O(sqrt(N))` vs. `O(N)`) instead of making parallel the inefficient implementation

Comment: Yes, txt_result is a UI textbox...

Yeah I know that I can use a more efficient prime tester, can that version be parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallelizing the outer loop should be enough. You are probably not going to run the program in a machine with more processors than outer loops!

```
Parallel.For(fromInclusive: 2, toExclusive: fPrime + 1, i =>
{
    for (int j = 2; j <= fPrime; j++)
    {

        if (i != j && i % j == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }

    }

    if (isPrime)
    {
        if (txt_result.InvokeRequired)
        {
            txt_result.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { txt_result.Text = txt_result.Text + "..." + i; });
        }
        else
        {
            txt_result.Text = txt_result.Text + "..." + i;
        }
    }
    isPrime = true;
});
txt_result.Text = txt_result.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Done";
```

Answer (score 1):

Better algorithm usually beats worse (but parallelized) one:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Primes(int upTo) {
  if (upTo <= 1)
    yield break;

  yield return 2; // Special case: the only even prime

  List<int> primes = new List<int>() { };

  for (int number = 3; number <= upTo; number += 2) {
    int max = (int)(Math.Sqrt(number) + 0.5);
    bool isPrime = true;

    foreach (var div in primes)
      if (div > max)
        break;
      else if (number % div == 0) {
        isPrime = false;

        break;
      }

    if (isPrime) {
      primes.Add(number);

      yield return number;
    }
  }
}

...

txt_result.Text = string.Join(", ", Primes(1000000));
```

And you'll have

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, ... 999959, 999961, 999979, 999983
```

in a fraction of second

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to update the UI using parallel foreach, you could write a method to return all of the primes

```
        private static List<int> PrimeNumbers(int input)
        {
            var bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(2, input), x =>
            {
                var isPrime = true;
                Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(2, input), (y, state) =>
                {
                    if ((x != y) && (x % y) == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        state.Break();
                    }
                });
                if (isPrime)
                    bag.Add(x);
            });

            return bag.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: the items in bag will not be in order so the right way to update the textbox would be ``` txt_result.Text = string.Join("...",PrimeNumbers(1000)); ```